# Ajax issues with ruby views

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to update the vote counts when I click on like or dislike by using ajax so the page don't have to reload.  The buttons seem to be working in the server logs and I'm not getting any errors in the console logs.

The vote counts are not updating unless I refresh the page.  How can I get the vote counts to update with ajax/json?

Show View with buttons

```
<span class="up"><%= @lyric.get_upvotes.size %> </span>
          <%= link_to like_lyric_path(@lyric), class: 'voteup', remote: true, data: { type: :json }, method: :get do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <% end %>
            <span class="down"><%= @lyric.get_downvotes.size %></span>
          <%= link_to dislike_lyric_path(@lyric), class: 'votedown', remote: true, data: { type: :json }, method: :get do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <% end %>
```

JS

```
    $('.voteup')
  .on('ajax:send', function () { $(this).addClass('loading'); })
  .on('ajax:complete', function () { $(this).removeClass('loading'); })
  .on('ajax:error', function () { $(this).after('<div class="error">There was an issue.</div>'); })
  .on('ajax:success', function () { 
    $('.up').html('<%=escape_javascript @lyric.get_upvotes.size.to_s %>');
    $('.down').html('<%=escape_javascript @lyric.get_downvotes.size.to_s %>');
  });

    </script>

      <script>

    $('.votedown')
  .on('ajax:send', function () { $(this).addClass('loading'); })
  .on('ajax:complete', function () { $(this).removeClass('loading'); })
  .on('ajax:error', function () { $(this).after('<div class="error">There was an issue.</div>'); })
  .on('ajax:success', function () { 
    $('.up').html('<%=escape_javascript @lyric.get_upvotes.size.to_s %>');
    $('.down').html('<%=escape_javascript @lyric.get_downvotes.size.to_s %>');
  });

    </script>
```

Controller

```
def upvote
    @lyric.upvote_by current_user

     respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to :back }
        format.json { render json: { data: @lyric.get_upvotes.size} }
    format.js { render :layout => false }

    end

end

def downvote
    @lyric.downvote_by current_user

         respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to :back }
        format.json { render json: { data: @lyric.get_downvotes.size } }
        format.js { render :layout => false }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS loaded once page is fetched will remain static. So the lines `$('.up').html('<%=escape_javascript @lyric.get_upvotes.size.to_s %>');` and 
`$('.down').html('<%=escape_javascript @lyric.get_downvotes.size.to_s %>');` which need to be run on the server(as it is rails code, that executes on the server) to get the updated value of `@lyric.get_upvotes.size.to_S` will not work. Instead what you can do is, 
the `format.json` is already returning the `json` - `{data: 10}`....where 10 is suppose the number of votes(up or down whichever).

Modify the `ajax:success` of both `.voteup` and `.votedown` classes to this

```
$('.voteup').
on('ajax:success', function (result) { 
    $('.up').html(result.data + ' Upvotes');
});

$('.votedown').
on('ajax:success', function (result) { 
    $('.down').html(result.data + ' Downvotes');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction.  From another question, I saw they added function(e, data, status, xhr) to the javascript.  At first the html was not updating but worked when I added the code.